# Google Maps API polygon trim

Tags: api, google-maps, dictionary

I want to trim multiple polygons on each other, it works but not as expected.Here is my code written in JAVA

```
    String coords = "|5,5|5,20|20,20|20,5|5,5";

    String coords2 = "|8,10|12,10|12,17|8,17|8,10";

    String coords3 = "|16,12|18,12|18,15|16,15|16,12";

    String aaa = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap" +
            "&center=10,10"+
            "&zoom=4"+
            "&size=600x600" +
            "&sensor=false" +
            "&path=weight:0|fillcolor%3ablue" + coords + coords2 + coords3 +
            "";
    URL url = new URL(aaa);
    BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(url);
    displayQRCode(read);
```

And the result is something like this: [Google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKfxK.png)

But i want to get something like this: [Right Google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olRqh.png)

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10),
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    var coords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(5,5),
        new google.maps.LatLng(5, 20),
        new google.maps.LatLng(20, 20),
        new google.maps.LatLng(20, 5),
        new google.maps.LatLng(5, 5)
    ];

    var coords2 = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(8, 10),
        new google.maps.LatLng(12,10),
        new google.maps.LatLng(12, 17),
        new google.maps.LatLng(8, 17),
        new google.maps.LatLng(8, 10)
    ];          

    var coords3 = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(16, 12),
        new google.maps.LatLng(18, 12),
        new google.maps.LatLng(18, 15),
        new google.maps.LatLng(16, 15),
        new google.maps.LatLng(16, 12)
    ];
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [coords, coords2, coords3],
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#00FF00',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    alert(coords);
    polygon.setMap(map);
  }
```

api drawer cuts the shape when it draws,

Comment: [The posted code displays the correct map for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/m68035ts/1/)

Comment: [Looks like your problem is with the static map API version](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&center=10,10&zoom=4&size=600x600&path=weight:0|fillcolor%3ablue|5,5|5,20|20,20|20,5|5,5|8,10|12,10|12,17|8,17|8,10|16,12|18,12|18,15|16,15|16,12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like a bug in the static maps renderer.  You get different results with different orders of the points.

[Issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8860)

your order: [static map 1](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&center=10,10&zoom=4&size=600x600&path=weight:0|fillcolor%3ablue|5,5|5,20|20,20|20,5|5,5|8,10|12,10|12,17|8,17|8,10|16,12|18,12|18,15|16,15|16,12)

[image: static map 1]

opposite order: [static map 2](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&center=10,10&zoom=4&size=600x600&path=weight:0|fillcolor%3ablue|5,5|5,20|20,20|20,5|5,5|16,12|18,12|18,15|16,15|16,12|8,10|12,10|12,17|8,17|8,10)

[image]